# How to use "of" preposition (POSSESSION)

Tags: prepositions

I read that the preposition "of" is used to show possession, belonging, or origin. For example:

> a friend of mine
>
> employees of the company
>
> a habit of mine
>
> the love of a good woman
>
> I hear the bark of a puppy.

I understand some but sometimes I don't understand well how to use article (a,the) before or after "of".
For example.

> a habit of mine

Can I say "the habit of mine "?

> the love of a good woman
>
> Can I say "the love of the good woman "?

Could you please tell me the different meanings of those sentences if I change articles?

Answer (score 5):

While you *could* use both "a" and "the" in your examples, it's much more common to use "of" in the indefinite case.

When using **a**:
You're talking about no particular item, but one among a bunch of others. the "of"-part serves as reducing the size of that bunch.

> *a habit* - well, there are many habits out there
> *a habit of mine* - one of the few habits I have
>
> *the love* - now, that term is mighty unspecific, isn't it?
> *the love of a good woman* - oh, *that* kind of love, I see.

When using **the**:
You're already talking about a very distinct subset (namely one occurrence) and other ways of showing that are available.

> *the habit of mine* - my habit / that habit (i was talking about)
> *the love of the good woman* - that good woman's love / her love